# Application of trigonometry : boat distance

Tags: trigonometry

The height of a light house is meter.The angle of depression of 2 ships on opposite sides of the light house are observed to be $30$ and $45$ degree .Find the distance between 2 ships

Comment: Please provide an explaination of what you have done, if you have,because no one likes to  do other people's homework...

Answer (score 2):

In $\triangle ABD$ $$BD=h m$$ and in $\triangle ACD$ $$DC=\frac{h}{\tan 30^o}m$$ hence, the distance between two ships is $$BD+DC=h+\frac{h}{\frac1{\sqrt{3}}}$$ $$=h(1+\sqrt3)m$$

[image: See the Image]